# Vue router doesn't route to specified location

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm using vue with vue-router and route doesn't work when routing to children route.

```
  {
    path: '/user',
    name: 'User',
    component: User,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'profile',
        component: Profile,
      },
    ],
  }
```

**Programmatically routing to /user/profile**

```
<template>
    <div>
            <button @click="goToUserProfile()">create new</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  methods: {
    goToUserProfile() {
      this.$router.push('/user/profile')    // Routing doesn't work
       .catch(console.log);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: What is the error (if any)? Have you tried this.$router.push({name: 'whatever you named your route'}) ?

Comment: When I was using 
this.$router.push('/user/profile');
no error were thrown

but when I used 
this.$route.push({name: '/user/profile'});
error thrown '[vue-router] Route with name '/user/profile' does not exist'

Comment: check your route and look at the name property of your route

Comment: You can try to add a `name: 'UserProfile'` to the nested route, and then do programmatic navigation to `UserProfile` like `this.$router.push({ name: 'UserProfile' });`

Comment: Now Error thrown says "NavigationDuplicated"

Comment: @palaѕн doesn't work

Comment: There might be some other issue with your code. Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening. Please note: do not add the full code of your app. Just to show the issue add some small text in the templates like "This is User component", "This is profile".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your ensure that you put `<router-view></router-view>` in User Component template to make the nested (children) routes displayed.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="goToUserProfile()">create new</button>
        <router-view></router-view>   <!-- placeholder for children routes -->
    </div> 
</template>
```

Then you can access by both
`this.$router.push('/user/profile')` and `this.$router.push({ name: 'UserProfile' })`

As Vue router document states:
**To render components into this nested outlet, we need to use the children option in VueRouter.**

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Hope this help.

Comment: I was not adding <router-view> for nested routing. Thats why URL changes but the component doesn't render. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

give a route name "Profile" for "/user/profile"

```js
  {
    path: '/user',
    name: 'User',
    component: User,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'profile',
        name: "Profile",
        component: Profile,
      },
    ],
  }
```

navigation use route name

```js
this.$router.push({name: "Profile"});
```

your User component should declare like this

User.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <p>this is user component</p>
    <!-- your Profile component will replace this route-view -->
    <route-view /> 
</div>
</template>
```

### demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-bash-6dl7m

Comment: Now Error thrown says "NavigationDuplicated"

Comment: Because you already in this route, you can navigate from other route to "Profile" route

Comment: If I declare profile route as a parent container (i.e not in children) then it works perfectly fine. But I want profile to be as a child route.